# How can you catch memory corruption in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, crash

I have an std::string which appears to be getting corrupted somehow. Sometimes the string destructor will trigger an access violation, and sometimes printing it via std::cout will produce a crash.

If I pad the string in a struct as follows, the back_padding becomes slightly corrupted at a relatively consistant point in my code:

```
struct Test {
    int front_padding[128] = {0};
    std::string my_string;
    int back_padding[128] = {0};
};
```

Is there a way to protect the front and back padding arrays so that writing to them will cause a exception or something? Or perhaps some tool which can be used to catch the culprit writing to this memory?

Platform: Windows x64 built with MSVC.

Comment: The tool you need is a bounds checker. If you're using C++ standard library containers, you might be able to turn on checked iterators.

Comment: asan/valgrind might help?

Comment: If you use a debugger you could throw a watch point on the padding. Chances are you have UB in your code that is not directly related to the string.

Comment: MSVC should have an address sanitizer as of 2019 v16.9 - that does exactly what you're asking, automatically. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you have to solve problem of code sanitation, which is quite a broad topic. It sounds like you may have either out-of-bound write, or use of a dangling pointer or even a race condition in using a pointer, but in latter case bug's visibility is affected by obsevation, like the proverbial cat in quantum superposition state.

A dirty way to debug source of such rogue write is to create a data breakpont. It is especially effective if bug appears to be deterministic and isn't a "heisenbug". It is possible in MSVS during debug session. In gdb it is possible by using watch breakpoints.

You can point at the std::string storage or, in your experimental case, at the front padding array to in attempt to trigger breakpoint where a write operation occurs.

Comment: Data breakpoints were the solution, thank you. I set a data breakpoint on one of the consistantly changing padding array indexes, and trapped the application at the exact moment when the data was being modified. This callstack gave me the clue I needed to resolve the issue. For those interested, the callstack was deep within the Boost Signal library, which led me to realise I had passed a lambda as a callback to an object using boost signals, but this lambda was going out of scope and so when it got called, undefined behaviour was occuring in the form of stack corruption.

Answer (score 1):

> How can you catch memory corruption in C++?

The best way with a modern compiler is to compile with an [*address sanitizer*](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer). This inserts exactly the sort of guard areas you describe around automatic (stack) and dynamic (heap) allocations, and detects when they're trampled. It's built into Clang, GCC and MSVC.

If you don't have compiler support, or need to diagnose the problem in an existing binary without recompiling, you can use [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org).

The sanitized executable runs at full speed, although it's doing more work and deliberately has a less cache-friendly memory layout; expect it to be about 2x slower than an equivalent un-instrumented build.

Running under valgrind is much slower (expect 10x-30x for memcheck), but will catch more types of error, and is your only option if you can't recompile.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but for this particular problem bared no fruit. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Which one? The sanitizer? Valgrind? Your guard areas are huge, and you didn't say where in the back padding corruption occurs, so you may need to instruct whichever tool you try to leave larger gutters, and/or track dynamic allocations more aggressively (although you haven't said how your objects are allocated)

Comment: I tried the address sanitizer in VS2019, but the issue no longer manifested with this enabled. I didn't get round to trying Valgrind though. I also tried using GFlags to detect heap allocation errors without success. The issue was in a stack allocated std::string and the corruption I saw was 8 bytes of giberish around index 380 of the back_padding array which was a char[1024] in practice.

Comment: 380 bytes is so far away that the address sanitizer may have seen it as a legal write to a completely different object. I don't know if you can choose to use larger redzones around allocations - even valgrind might require some configuration to catch that.